# Invalid SQL statement error while executing data which is fetched from SQL script file

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, plsql

I have a code which fetches data from a given sql file and returns it.

```
public String importSQL(Connection conn) throws Exception
{
Statement st = null;
String filedata=null;

File file = new File("C:\\Users\\Admin\\Desktop\\Chat\\Scripts\\date.sql");
try {
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
    char current;
    while (fis.available() > 0) {
    current = (char) fis.read();
    filedata=filedata+current;
    System.out.print(current);
  }
} catch (IOException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
return filedata;
}
```

this code will be called in this code:

```
public static void main (String args [])
throws Exception
{
 Connection conn = null;
   Statement stmt = null;
  String JDBC_DRIVER = "com.oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver";  
    String DB_URL ="jdbc:oracle:thin:@//server:1521/ser_name";


    String USER = "abc";
    String PASS = "abc";

    Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
    conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL,USER,PASS);
stmt = conn.createStatement();
ScriptRunner runner = new ScriptRunner();
String filedata=runner.importSQL(conn);
stmt.execute(filedata);
stmt.close();
}
```

the date.sql file has:

```
declare
tdate varchar2(30); 
begin 
  select sysdate into tdate from dual; 
  dbms_output.put_line(tdate); 
end;
```

everything else runs fine however when it comes to "stmt.execute(filedata);" it says "ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement"

even the anonymous block runs fine..

Please help me.
Thank you.

Comment: Try to add / symbol at new line after end;

Comment: Tried that, no use. are there any junk characters being added while accessing data?

Comment: Change `tdate varchar2(30);` to `tdate date;` in date.sql file  and give a try

Comment: Make `System.out.println(filedata);` before `stmt.execute(filedata);` to make sure you are executing correct SQL query. Also, when you receive `ORA-00900`, do you have any additional information (line number, piece of SQL code, etc.) in the error message?

Comment: Got it. I have initialized filedata=null; the script was taking that null and further query. Now I initialized filedata=""; Its working fine now. Thank you :)

Comment: @hinotf - the `/` character is not part of the SQL or PL/SQL language but is only used as a terminator by client tools such as SQL*Plus.